# How do I put a selectable dynamic list on a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

How do I put a selectable dynamic list on a jquery dialog.  What I am wanting to do is when the user clicks a button a dialog appears and the list is populated by results from the sqlite database.  The user then clicks the result he/she desires and then a button on the dialog to load the results.

My dialog code is the following... I'd like a list to appear on the dialog when it is opened that displays SQLite results.

```
function setImportDialog()
{
    $('#importDialog').dialog({
        resizeable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons:{
            "Import Test": function(){
                if( isWindows() ) 
                {
                    log("Importing Test Data: ");
                    importTestData(); //' here is where it would grab the selected item and perform actions on said item
                }
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
        } });
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue? You're having trouble with AJAX or opening the Dialog? Or loading AJAX into the dialog?

Comment: Seems like the big step your missing is an AJAX service request to pull in the information for the dialog.

Comment: Well I know how to get the AJAX/SQLite request to populate the "list".  I don't know what code/object to use to put a selectable "list" on my dialog.  Do I set that up in this code? the html code? and how do I make it dynamic?  I guess I need help structuring the code and figuring what objects to use to accomplish my goal.  I hope this makes sense, will clarify if not.[

Comment: something along the lines of this.. but on a dialog.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/